# Media Codec Error Resilience

Tags: coding-theory

I'm an entire outsider to computer science eventhough I've been programming for so many years.

As we know, modern audio-visual media codecs are essentially entropy codings of subjective preceptual information. Well known codecs such as AVC, HEVC, AAC, AC3 are highly efficient at compressing AV data.

So I wonder, what about error resilience? How well does HEVC/H.265 handle erroneous code streams, how does it recover from errors? What design decisions (drop malformed code segment or pass it on ignoring error as if it's correct) have been made by its developers?